# two <h4>, <img> and<p> tags are grouped in separate<div>s and I've used float for img, used <br> to separate each other <divs> but still they overlap

Tags: html, css

two h4, img and p tags are grouped in separate < div>s and I've used float for img, used 
 to separate  from each other  but still they overlap.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUxli.png
this is the image with the output.

I'm new to this, can anybody please help. Thank you.

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 0px;
  /* float: left; */
}

.service {
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
    <div class="service">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
        <img src="image.jfif" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus ab nulla dolorum autem nisi officiis blanditiis voluptatem hic, assumenda aspernatur facere ipsam nemo ratione cumque magnam enim fugiat reprehenderit expedita.</p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="service">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
        <img src="image.jfif" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus ab nulla dolorum autem nisi officiis blanditiis voluptatem hic, assumenda aspernatur facere ipsam nemo ratione cumque magnam enim fugiat reprehenderit expedita.</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try nesting your code in a `container` that is flexed with a column flex-direction. Then I would put your `<h4>`'s before the `service` div and flex that div also, but use a `flex-direction: row;` See the CSS changes I made.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  /* float: left; */
}

.service {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
   <div class="service">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus ab nulla dolorum autem nisi officiis blanditiis voluptatem hic, assumenda aspernatur facere ipsam nemo ratione cumque magnam enim fugiat reprehenderit expedita.</p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
   <div class="service">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus ab nulla dolorum autem nisi officiis blanditiis voluptatem hic, assumenda aspernatur facere ipsam nemo ratione cumque magnam enim fugiat reprehenderit expedita.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```